# SQL Server query failed with RODBC connection, works in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

Hello and thanks in advance.

I'm using the R package `RODBC`to connect to a SQL Server database and run a query to DELETE data in a table.  When I run other queries like SELECT statements etc... the query runs fine or at least I get a detailed error.  The query below doesn't give much more than a failure"

```
bulk <- odbcConnect(dsn="DSN", uid = "UID", pwd = "PWD",case="nochange", colQuote=c(), tabQuote=c() )

prodnum <- 9803

  sqlQuery(bulk,
           paste("DELETE FROM [schema].[table] WHERE date = (SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND ID IN ('"
                  ,prodnum
                  ,"')"
                  , sep=""), believeNRows=FALSE)
```

I've asked others to run the query through SQL Server using my credentials and it seems to work fine for them.  R just returns this error:

```
[1] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'DELETE FROM [schema].[table] WHERE date = (SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND ID IN ('9803)'"
```

Comment: Is that the actual error and SQL that you're trying to run? `IN ('9803)` isn't right.

Comment: @duffn I removed the single quotes but still no luck, and again someone else ran that same query through SQL server and it worked fine.  I just keep getting that error :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that if there is no data in the table, that error will return.  I inserted some data into the table then tried running the delete query after.  Worked 100% of the time.

Comment: Why does it fail with no data?

Comment: 2019 and this is still a problem. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I've run into this today where there was data in the table. None matching conditions but still that's pretty dumb.